# Array of pointers of arrays not working in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

On the beginning of the code i have the folowing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef int8_t matriz3[3][3];
typedef int8_t matriz1[3];
typedef matriz3* matriz4[4];
typedef matriz4* matriz6[6];
typedef int8_t store[40][6];
```

On main I have:

```
matriz3 identidade = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
matriz3 ctbh = {{0, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};
matriz3 ctbah = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}};
matriz3 ctb180 = {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}};
matriz4 opbt = {&identidade, &ctbh, &ctbah, &ctb180};

int i, j;

    matriz3 *p;

    p = opbt[0];

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%d %d \n", p[i][j], &identidade[i][j]);
        };
    };
```

The logic that I used was that I wanted to loop through the first 4 arrays. So I put their addresses in a array that should contain pointers to "matriz3" arrays. I then created a pointer "p" to an array "matriz3", made it point to the same address as opbt[0] wich is the same address as "identidade". But it wasn't working. So I decided to look at the addresses, that is what that loop does. I got

```
2751995 2751995
2751998 2751996
2752001 2751997
2752004 2751998
2752007 2751999
2752010 2752000
2752013 2752001
2752016 2752002
2752019 2752003
```

They start the same, but one goes step 1, the other step 3. How can I make this work? What is going wrong? Should arrays's addresses raise step 1?

Comment: You understand the second column but not the first, is that correct?

Comment: @user3159253 Yes. Shouldt they be the same?

Comment: `p` is a *pointer to a* matriz3, and `identidade` is just a matriz3. So surely you want to use `&(*p)[i][j]` and `&identidade[i][j]`?

Comment: @immibis, that is just it! I figured it out last night, tried to answer my own question but couldn't.

Comment: @immibis, what I thought was "well, it seems it's looping through identidade[i], but not it's elements. So, if p is the address of the array im reffering to, *p is it, and i want to loop through its elements, so I maybe should separate (*p)[i][j]." I had already read threads about the difference of "int (*array)[i][j]" and "int* array[i][j]", but I didn't connect those cases to mine. So, the wrong case, *p[i][j], what does it mean???

Comment: @RFiischer `*p[i][j]` means `*((p[i])[j])`, or `p[i][j][0]`, or `(*(p + i))[j][0]`, or the [j][0]'th element of the i'th matriz3 after where p points to. (And `p[i][j]` is the address of that element)

Answer (score 0):

```
2751995 <-- address of identidade[0][0]
2751998 <-- address of identidade[1][0]
2752001 <-- address of identidade[2][0]
2752004 <-- address of ctbh[0][0]
2752007 <-- address of ctbh[1][0]
2752010 <-- address of ctbh[2][0]
2752013 <-- address of ctbah[0][0]
2752016 <-- address of ctbah[1][0]
2752019 <-- address of ctbah[2][0]
```

The addresses increase by three (within each `matriz3`) because you are iterating over the first dimension of each `matriz3`, not the second, like going down the leftmost column of a table without iterating along the rows. (The increment is steady when jumping from one `matriz3` to the next, because they occupy neighboring memory, because of the way you declared them and luck.)

It is not clear what you are trying to do, but if you want to iterate over all elements, you must add a third nested loop-- because a `matriz4` is three-dimensional.

Comment: The third nested loop is in the rest of the algorithm, but is irrelevant. I want that *p[i][j] gives the same as identidade[i][j], since their starting address is the same, and p is a pointer to the same type of array as identidade.

Comment: @RFiischer: Two pointers *of different type* can point to the same location in memory, but if you increment them both, they may then point to different locations. The variable `identidade` is a `matriz3`, which effectively means it is a `matriz1*`, it points to the beginning of `{1, 0, 0}`, and `identidade+1` points to the beginning of `{0, 1, 0}`. But `p` is a `matriz3*`; it points to the beginning of `identidade` and `p+1` points to the beginning of `ctbh`.